# Reference C# library in C++ Program, But can't other PC

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, dll

I made ClassLib to use C#.
And made another C++ win32 project.
This C++ Program Import C#'s tlb and can call lib's method successfuly.
But just work in development PC..

I have two file that is exe(made by c++) and dll(made by c#).
if i lay two file same folder on my development PC. It is work Successfuly.
But if i do same thing on another PC. That make happen.
CoCreateInstance() return null.

I don't know what is reason this problem..

Please teach me If you know.
C++ sources.----
stdafx.h

```
#pragma once
#include "targetver.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#import "pc3dx.dll" no_namespace, rename("PostMessage","CdmPostMessage")
#import "MailCtrl.tlb" no_namespace named_guids
```

Mail.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#pragma once

struct MailInterface;

class Mail
{
public:
Mail(void);
~Mail(void);

bool SendMail();

_bstr_t m_SmtpServer;
int m_Port;
_bstr_t m_From;
_bstr_t m_To;
_bstr_t m_Title;
_bstr_t m_Body;

private:

MailInterface *mailInter;

};
```

Mail.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Mail.h"

using namespace std;

Mail::Mail(void)
{
}

Mail::~Mail(void)
{
}

bool Mail::SendMail()
{
bool result;
mailInter = NULL;

CoInitialize(NULL);   
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MailCtrll,    
                           NULL,    
                           CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,    
                           IID_MailInterface,    
                           reinterpret_cast<void**>(&mailInter));   

mailInter->SetMail(m_SmtpServer
    ,m_Port
    ,m_From
    ,m_To
    ,m_Title
    ,m_Body);

result = (mailInter->Send())?true:false;

return result;
}
```

&mailInter is returned null if excuted on other pc.

This is C# sources. ----

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MailCtrl
{
[Guid("A5A420C2-F419-4063-B9A8-FC45737A2B37")]
public interface MailInterface
{
    bool SetMail(String m_Server, int m_Port ,String m_From, String m_To, String m_Title, String m_body);
    bool Send();
    bool CheckArg();
    String GetResultMsg();
}

[Guid("FC979228-1F8B-4D04-8CD8-546B0B64E616")]
public class MailCtrll : MailInterface
{      
    private String m_Server="";
    private int m_Port=0;
    private String m_From = "";
    private String m_To = "";
    private String m_Title = "";
    private String m_Body = "";

    private MailMessage mail=null;
    private SmtpClient smtpServer=null;

    private String resultMsg = "";

    public bool SetMail(String s_Server, int s_Port ,String s_From, String s_To, String s_Title, String s_body)
    {
        m_Server = s_Server;
        m_Port = s_Port;
        m_From = s_From;
        m_To = s_To;
        m_Title = s_Title;
        m_Body = s_body;

        return true;
    }

    public bool Send()
    {
        mail = new MailMessage();

        try
        {
            smtpServer = new SmtpClient(m_Server);

            if (CheckArg() == false)
            {
                return false;
            }

            mail.From = new MailAddress(m_From);
            mail.To.Add(m_To);
            mail.Subject = m_Title;
            mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            mail.Body = m_Body;
            mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

            smtpServer.Port = m_Port;
            smtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

            smtpServer.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool CheckArg()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_Server))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (m_Port < 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_From))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_To))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_Title))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_Body))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public String GetResultMsg()
    {
        return resultMsg;
    }
}
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: are you sure that the sutiable .NET framwork is installed on the other machine ?

Comment: Why did you ignore the returned HRESULT?

Comment: Who is doing the registration of DLL on another machine?

Comment: humam-helfawi // thank you. I tried to build C# probram using all of .NetFramwork ver(2.0, 3.0 3.0client 3.5, 4.0 4.5) after read your comment. But sadly Couldn't solve problem.

Comment: david-heffernan // I add to source if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && mailInter != nullptr). thank you.

Comment: Ajay // It is me. I want to regist this application and dll on ServerPC. And Excute this every morning  using task scheduler. This program is checking posible access the other servers. And send mail reulst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you registered the library as a COM component?
each COM library should be register on the target machine. in development system, registration will be done by visual studio when building the project.
You can do it manually or by installer scripts on the client machine.
the `RegAsm.exe` tool will help you! just type:
    regasm.exe fileName.dll /tlb:fileName.Tlb
It will generate .TLB from dll and registers it on the machine.
and if you want register it manually (without regasm) take a look at this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h627s4zy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I made tlb File using RegAsm.exe or set C# Program's property. If i didn't make tlb file, I think that my C++ Program never success compile. Thank you comment!

Comment: I mean you should copy .DLL file on the target machine and then generate .TLB file (not just moving). the goal of RegAsm.Exe is registering the library as COM component not just generating .TLB file. anyway you may use regsvr32.exe.

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood your reply. I check hr message. It is say that class is not registed. So i agree your opinion. I should regist library on other PC. I will try this. I will comment again. Thank you

Comment: I tried. It is all did in another server PC. I copy RegAsm.exe to be MailCtrl.dll file From windows/Microsoft.NET/Framwork64/4.0.30319. And tried enter command on CMD for author. i tried  [regasm MailCtrl.dll] and [regasm MailCtrl.dll /tlb:MailCtrl.tlb] and [regasm MailCtrl.dll regfile:MailCtrl.reg]  All of them say Types registered successfully. But still say Class is not registed when i excute my program. I am very confusing. But Thank you for your kind.

Comment: mehrdad safa // Good morning. I solved this. First. My c++ program is Win32 Console. I can't sure that but i think Win32 is maybe 32bit program. Second. I thought that setting bit in program is target os bit. But It is wrong maybe. So! I must build C# program target x86, because the calling c++ program is win32. And..This is important. I must used regasm in Framework folder. should not Framework64. So i use regasm in Framework/v4.0.30319. Finally could solve this problem Thank you.